# Perl equivalent of the `&` placeholder in the "vi" editor

Tags: regex, perl

Using the **vi** screen editor I would do this

```
%s/^drop table .*/exec rename_table('&')/g
```

which allows me to reformat the found string. I need to do same in Perl.

I have written a module to which I pass the pattern `$regexp` and replacement `$newtxt` strings.

This module does

```
if ( $_ !~ /$regexp/ ) {
    print FOUT;
}
else {
    s/$regexp/$newtxt/g;
    print FOUT;
}
```

and I tried

```
perl_swap( '(drop table .*);' , 'echo $3;' )
```

hoping the found table name—the third argument—would get mapped to `$3`.

Comment: vi `&` expands to the whole matched string, including `drop table`. This is not what you want.

Comment: Yes the perl code is verbose but cannot be changed, as is the calling language a custom shell.  The script wants to process files with these commands to basically replace them;  so the "&" as in vi would work just fine for me - my example was just getting zealous to just consume the last token in the example.

Comment: I'm not saying it's verbose; I'm saying it's silly and contains duplicated code for no reason. And what does that have to do with the calling language?

Comment: ... speaking of verbosity, the code is curiously non-verbose: `s/$regexp/$newtxt/g; print FOUT;` could have been written `$_ =~ s/$regexp/$newtxt/g; print FOUT $_;` if you wanted to be completely explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [String::Substitution](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::Substitution)'s `gsub_modify`.

```
use String::Substitution qw( gsub_modify );

my $pat = 'drop table (.*);';
my $repl = 'echo $1;';
local $_ = 'drop table foo;';
gsub_modify($_, $pat, $repl);
say;
```

Comment: I thought you frowned upon "it doesn't work" as a problem description?

Comment: I don't have a question beyond my comment. It is you who wrote about "solutions that don't work".

Comment: @Borodin Refer to [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Substitution#DESCRIPTION). (I admit it could be clearer.)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is (mostly) impossible. Perl does not treat any character in the replacement string specially.

What you can do is capture (explicitly or implicitly) the matched text and use one of the special variables in the replacement part (`$1`, `$2`, `$&`, etc), but that only works because the replacement part is *code*. In your case, `s/$regexp/$newtxt/g`, the only variable is `$newtxt`, and its content is not rescanned for further expansion.

You might be able to trick the `s/$regexp/$newtxt/g` code by passing an object with overloaded stringification as `$newtxt`, but it would be much better (i.e. easier and more maintainable) to change the code. In fact, the existing code is already a bit silly:

```
if ($_ !~ /$regexp/)
{
    print FOUT;
}
else
{
    s/$regexp/$newtxt/g;
    print FOUT;
}
```

can be simplified to just

```
s/$regexp/$newtxt/g;
print FOUT;
```

To allow dynamic replacement, the natural interface is to use a function, not a string:

```
s/$regexp/ $newtxt->() /eg;
```

Here `/e` tells Perl that the replacement part is to be parsed as a block of code, not a quoted string. The call would look like

```
perl_swap( 'drop table (.*);' , sub { "echo $1;" } );
```

`$1` being the contents of the first capture group `(` `)`.

On the other hand, if the interface must use strings only, you need to do a bit more manual work or use a module that does it for you. For example:

```
use Data::Munge qw(replace);
...
$_ = replace($_, $regexp, $newtxt, 'g');
```

This allows calls of the form

```
perl_swap( 'drop table (.*);' , 'echo $1;' );
```

because [`Data::Munge::replace`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge#replace-STRING,-REGEX,-REPLACEMENT,-FLAG) explicitly scans for and expands `$` sequences such as `$1` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl

    # always use these two
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    # use autodie to automatically die on open errors
    use autodie;

    my $s = 'drop table FOO';
    print "$s\n";

    if( $s =~ s/^drop table (.*)/exec rename_table('&')/ ){
        my $captured = $1;
        $s =~ s/\&/$captured/;
    }

    print "$s\n";
```

Comment: `autodie` is redundant here. This code is semantically wrong if `$s` already contains `&` anywhere. Never use `$1` without making sure the previous regex match succeeded. You don't need to escape `&` in a regex.

Comment: `autodie` is no more redundant than `use strict;` and `use warning;` You should always include them in your code. And you should escape all non-alphanumeric characters because you don't know if they will be used as a meta-character in the future.

Comment: I disagree on `autodie`, but OK. As for (currently non-special) non-alphanumeric characters: They won't be used as regex meta-characters because that would break all existing programs.

Comment: @melpomene You are correct about `&` but I was fooled by the `/g` modifier. The pattern is anchored to the beginning of the string, so multiple `&` are not a problem. That means the `/g` modifier is superfluous. And misleading. I have corrected the code.